# What statistical model would best analyze the data from the experimental task described below?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-logit

I conducted a language task that involved picture descriptions across two language contexts. A set of 18 pictures was given to 20 participants and they were asked to describe them using language A. The same set of 18 pictures was equally given to 20 different participants to describe using language B. The 18 pictures were designed in such a way that each of them belonged to any of the three categories of cat1,cat2 and cat3 with each category having six pictures.

Each picture produced a single description so that every participant gave 18 different descriptions. A total of 720 different descriptions were realized across the two language contexts.

The descriptions were analyzed out of which FoRs were identified. An FoR is a language property that gives exact locations of objects within space. Across the 720 responses, 6 different FoRs were identified plus a seventh category where no FoR was used.

The goal of the task was to investigate the role that language context plays in the choice of an FoR in picture descriptions

All the participants were multilinguals with each having the same first(L1), second(L2) and third(L3) languages though not necessarily acquired in that order. Others had L4, and L5. The levels of proficiency across the languages differed.

From the task description above, the following are realized
Response variable = choice of FoR (7 different levels: six FoR choices and 1 no FoR choice)
Independent variable = language context (2 levels-language A and language B)
Possible Random effects = picture categories(cat1,cat2,cat3);subjects.
Others factors to consider - differing levels of language proficiencies etc.

What best approach would be used to analyze such a data set. I have thought of the Multinomial Mixed Effects Model using the 'MCMCglmm' package in R but it is not very straightforward. Any other suggestion will be highly appreciated.